# How to extract the alias from a table with regex?

Tags: java, sql, regex

I need to get the alias of a table in java, using for this regex.
For example, for this string: `FROM lineitem A INNER JOIN orders B ON (B.O_ORDERKEY = A.L_ORDERKEY) INNER JOIN customer C ON (C.C_CUSTKEY = B.O_ORDERKEY)` I should get **A, B, C**.
How can I do this using regex in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all our inputs are similar to the question, we would start with a simple expression and test it later with more inputs:

```
\s+([A-Z])\s+
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jYDyzt/1)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\s+([A-Z])\\s+";
final String string = "FROM lineitem A INNER JOIN orders B ON (B.O_ORDERKEY = A.L_ORDERKEY) INNER JOIN customer C ON (C.C_CUSTKEY = B.O_ORDERKEY)";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]